# Update list with nested list with list comprehension

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I have a list like the following which is generated by reading a csv file:

```
cr = csv.reader(fileName, delimiter='\t')
lineList =  [line for line in cr]
print lineList

>>>[['TestTest', 'kvhx', 'Status', 'segment'], ['', '41000020003000000', '', 'aaa'], ['', '41000020004000000', '', 'dddd'], ['', '41000020005000000', '', 'ccc'], ['', '41000020006000000', '', 'aaa'], ['', '41000020007000000', '', 'eeen'], ['', '41000020008000000', '', 'dds'], ['', '41000020009000000', '', 'ssd'], ['', '41000020010000000', '', 'eee'], ['', '41000020011000000', '', 'qq'], ['', '']]
```

I like to update the list with the following list comprehension:

```
NewLineList =  [[line[0], (line[1][0:3] + ';' + line[1][3:7] + ';' + line[1][7:11]), line[2], line[3]]  for line in cr]
```

I am getting the error that the list index is out of range. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last item in the list is `['', '']` and doesnt have a `line[2]` and `line[3]`.  I suggest you trim that useless extra list off the end first.